# concatenating all files horizontally and only a specific column

Tags: linux, shell, gnu

In linux, is there a way to concatenate all the files in a directory that end with .out into one file? It would be even better if the final output file had them horizontally next to one another, rather than vertically. Even further, is it possible to only get the 6th column from each file (each column separated by a space).

I know I have been doing this in powershell. was wondering if linux can do this?

I know I can use

```
paste *.out > total.out
```

but how do I just paste the 6th column, which are separated by spaces?

Comment: It's hasn't much to do with Linux. Linux is just a kernel. It's about the programs that are installed, often the GNU system. And yes, you got awk, sed, bash, and many more at your disposal and they can do that.

Comment: Show two example files and how you want your final file to look like.

Answer (score 2):

Using bash and awk with temporary files to filter the sixth column of each `*.out` file.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a TEMPS

for name in *.out; do
    TEMPS+=($(mktemp $name.XXXXXXXX))
    awk '{ print $5 ;}' $name >${TEMPS[-1]}
done

paste -d ' ' "${TEMPS[@]}"

# Remove tmp files
rm "${TEMPS[@]}"
```

*Output using the example files from @daniel*

```
6 18 30
12 24 36
```

Comment: Unfortunately this just gives me a blank file.

Comment: What delimiter do you have in the `*.out` files?

Comment: Looks like this: Number of vacant sites: 2104

Comment: 2104 is position 5. Updated answer.

Comment: Ah i see. Is there a way to paste this to a file rather than the terminal?

Comment: Put it all in a file say `mypaste.sh` and run `bash mypaste.sh >myoutput.txt` or make `mypaste.sh` executable by `chmod a+x mypaste.sh` and run `./mypaste.sh >myoutput.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Save this script as a .sh file, then run it in your directory. This method uses `sponge` which you can install in Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install moreutils`

saveColumn6.sh

```
# Make total.out a blank file
rm total.out
> total.out
# Go through every file ending in '.out'
for i in *.out
do
  # cut out field 6, append it to total.out, and rewrite the file.
  cut -d ' ' -f6 $i | paste -d' ' total.out - | sponge total.out
done
```

Here are the input files I used to test this.

in0.out

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
```

in1.out

```
13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24
```

in2.out

```
25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36
```

Here is the output file I received

total.out

```
 6 18 30
 12 24 36
```

Note that there is a leading space in this new database, I couldn't figure out how to get rid of that.

As Nightcrawler mentioned, Linux isn't the relevent component. You're looking for `bash`, the command-line shell used by many GNU/Linux based systems.

Comment: I had to use sponge in order to simultaneously read and write to total.out. I would be interested if someone knew a way to do this without the sponge dependency.